# Regarding "cannot use time.Now() (type time.Time) as type "

Tags: go

Get "cannot use time.Now() (type time.Time) as type typetime in field value" with below type definition

```
import ("time")

type typetime time.Time 
type Friends struct {
   Name string
   Birthday typetime
}

John := Friends{Name:"John", Birthday:time.Now()}
```

If I replace typetime with direct type form (time.Time), there is no problem. what is GO's rule behind?? :>

Answer (score 1):

time.Time and typetime are different types (though they have the same underlying representations) so you need to convert the type.

```
John := Friends{Name: "John", Birthday: typetime(time.Now())}
```

Comment: thanks matt.s. However, why they are different and that sounds like `type mystringtype string` is different from string? interestingly, below code has no problem `type mystringtype string     type Friends struct { Name mystringtype}`

Comment: That's because literals will match any compatible type.  time.Now() isn't a literal.  "John" is.